# How to visualize data on a map using python in spark that came from csv?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `CSV` file that I have in `HDFS`. I am using the latest version of `Spark` and `Python 3.7`. How can I make it such that I can visualize the `CSV`?

I tried the following sample code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg

mydataframe = spark.read.csv("/diamonds.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")

display(mydataframe.select("color","price").groupBy("color").agg(avg("price")))
```

The issue is, all I see in the output is text that looks like the schema of the mydataframe as opposed to an actual chart or visualization.

There is a column for 'latitude' and 'longitude' that I would like to use to display on a map. How can I do that?

Comment: How big is your dataset ? Depending on this, you could convert your `pyspark` DataFrame to a `pandas` DataFrame

Comment: It is small, less than 30MB, though I want to be able to scale!

Comment: I guess you're working on Databricks platform. It's not that easy there, but maybe check the post here - they seem to have found some workaround: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/444/how-to-create-maps-in-databricks.html. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using python modules designed for geographic visualizations like geopandas?

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip( mydataframe["LONGITUDE"], mydataframe["LATITUDE"])]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(mydataframe, geometry=geometry)
gdf.plot()
```

See [Application GeoPandas and Spark](https://ncar.github.io/PySpark4Climate/tutorials/pyspark-geo-analysis/geopandas-and-spark/) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem which I worked on with data bricks platform. In a nutshell the idea looks like this:

1. Use OpenStreetMaps with [leafletjs](https://leafletjs.com/) to render map with overlays. Use [displayHTML](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/html-d3-and-svg.html) function from databricks notebook to render the HTML.
2. The markers are used to represent information on map.
3. For small datasets its not a problem to render a few markers. But for large datasets rendering is huge problem, with issues like browser being stuck, this could be circumvented by using [markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster). Marker cluster allows for a drilldown like functionality.

For any dataset which is huge enough to cause troubles on browser, I would suggest to rollup data in usable fashion yourself.